# removing client side validation errors in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I have a mvc form where users can add dynamic elements. I am using unobstrusive validation with MVC. 
I also have two buttons, one save as draft and the other submit. The submit button correctly triggers the validation including the dynamic elements that were added.

However i am having a hard time trying to clear validation attributes data-val-* on the client side if save as draft is clicked.

Whatever i do, i can never trigger form submit to call my action method. Obviously only then i could handle disabling the server side validation.

I have tried the following

```
                 $("#myform").submit(function () {
                    ---
                    //some code to check which submit button was clicked
                    //if save as draft was clicked, proceed below
                    ---
                    var settings = $("#myform").validate().settings;
                    for (var ruleIndex in settings.rules) {
                        delete settings.rules[ruleIndex];

                    $('#myform').clearErrors();

                    //$("#myform").removeData("validator")    
                    //    .removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
                    $("select").removeAttr("data-val-required");
                    $("select").removeAttr("data-val-number");

                    $("input").removeAttr("data-val-required");


                    if ($("#myform").valid()) {
                        alert("valid");  //I can reach here indicating that the form is valid at this point.But still my action  method is not called.
                    }
                }

             $.fn.clearErrors = function () {

                $(this).each(function () {

                    $(this).find(".field-validation-error").empty();
                    $(this).find(".input-validation-error").removeClass("input-validation-error");
                    $(this).trigger('reset.unobtrusiveValidation');
                });
            };
```

Comment: Suggest you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49377659/remove-required-validation-using-asp-net-core/49378613#comment85762135_49378613), including the comments and those in chat to understand why what you attempting to do is a bad idea.

Comment: Hi Stephen, I understand why you are saying this is a a bad idea. In my case i have a parent-child model, and i am adding child dynamically and there can be may children.It appears that i have to have the IsDraft property on all the child elements for the validator to work. (so i basically set all the child elements with the is draft variable set to YES on submission) I can definitely go down that path, but was curious to see why clearing validation is not working. Thanks!

Comment: At the least, you would need to remove all the `data-val="true"` attributes from all your elements, then remove the validator and re-parse it - `$("#myform").data('validator', null); $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#myform"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add formnovalidate attribute on your "save as draft" button as described in 
[Documentation for jqueryvalidation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-skipping-validation-on-submit).

Example :

```
<input type="submit" formnovalidate name="saveAsDraft" value="Cancel">
```

You might have to use class="cancel" attribute instead of formnovalidate attribute in case you are on a older version .
Example :

```
<input type="submit" class="cancel" name="saveAsDraft" value="Cancel">
```

Comment: Also, once you do a post using SaveAsDraft button , you can clear any model validation error in the action method before you return the view otherwise you will end up with refreshed view with validation errors visible. This will happen because if there are any validation errors in ModelState and Razor tries to render the view, it will add those validation errors in the view from ModelState.

Comment: Yes, i think all i was missing was the class="cancel" on my input submit button. Thanks for pointing this out.